# SQL Query Duplicates Values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm running a query to see who hasn't signed up for classes, and whenever I do it, it duplicates the student information and displays them twice. Any reason query wise it would be doing this?

Here is the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.grade, a.lastname, a.firstname, a.sid 
FROM aspen a 
LEFT JOIN gh g ON a.sid = g.sid 
WHERE g.sid IS NULL 
order by a.grade, a.lastname, a.firstname
```

Comment: The only way that could happen here is if there are duplicate rows in `aspen`.

Comment: That can't possibly happen with `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Are you sure all the columns are duplicated? Check for characters that are difficult to distinguish, like spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't interested in any data from `gh` simply use `not exists`

```
select grade, lastname, firstname, sid 
from aspen a 
where not exists (select * from gh where gh.sid = a.sid)
order by grade, lastname, firstname
```